# DataSnap XE returning TJSONObject as a string if json-min.js is replaced by json2.js to fix jQuery mobile

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, datasnap

json-min.js breaks some libraries such as jQuery mobile.  The work around is to replace the file with json2.js and replace js/* occurrences of toJSONString with JSON.stringify().

The Fix:
https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=53872

However, doing this makes typeof serverMethods().mymethod() return 'string' instead of 'object'.

Has anyone come across this issue and found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to copy the js files generated from XE2.  I'm not yet using XE2 in production BUT it is fixed in XE2 and copying the files did work.